# How to multiple a certain number in a string in C#

Tags: c#

I'm making a small tool in winform that makes my work a bit easier.

My goal is to make a tool that can change the numbers before every index.
This is a group of items with different indexes: 1695, 1696 etc... I want to multiply the number before every index for example by 2:

Input:

```
(group (index 2589) (item (6 1695 0) (12 1696 0) (18 1697 0) (24 1698 0)))
```

Output:

```
(group (index 2589) (item (12 1695 0) (24 1696 0) (36 1697 0) (48 1698 0)))
```

How can i split the string in a good way to target the numbers before the indexes?

Comment: The only one thing that comes to my mind is that, you can use ``Regex`` .

Comment: Is the above data literally a string in that format? Or is that just an abstract description of a data structure which is represented a different way in your code? It's unclear. If you can have any control over the format of your data then I would advise you to put it into a list structure with separate fields, before you attempt to process it. If not you'll need a preliminary step to process it into such a format, e.g. maybe regular expressions, as suggested above. It's too complicated to do a simple split, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do this. For example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\()(\d+)(?= \d+ \d+\))");
var input = "(group (index 2589) (item (6 1695 0) (12 1696 0) (18 1697 0) (24 1698 0)))";
// (group (index 2589) (item (12 1695 0) (24 1696 0) (36 1697 0) (48 1698 0)))
var output = regex.Replace(input, (match) => (int.Parse(match.Value) * 2).ToString());
```

The regular expression pattern here has three components which isolate the number to multiply.

`(?<=\()` Is a positive look behind, searching for an opening bracket.

`(\d+)` Matches the first number in the brackets - one or more digits

`(?= \d+ \d+\))` Is a positive look ahead, which searches for a space, one or more digits, followed by another space, another number and a closing bracket.

The resulting match of the regular expression is just the index number, so we can use a `MatchEvaluator` delegate to multiply that and replace in the original string.